# How can I prevent Google from indexing my Google+ page posts instead of the copy on my website?

Tags: google-search, search-engine-indexing, google+

I own a website and recently I have noticed that Google has indexed a lot of posts which I shared in my Google+ page for obtaining traffic. And when I type in a search query related to my website Google+ posts links are showing while some of my website links are neglected. [Please refer attached]

I have been getting a feeling that this might lead to a loss in traffic to my website. Moreover the captions which I add while sharing a particular posts in G+ was indexed by Google which might sometimes be misleading. I am very much worried about this, but not sure what causes it though.

I have checked G+ settings, but am unable to find any permissions or indexing settings that disallow Google to index the posts which I share.

[image: Search results of a search query web link and Google+ link]

Comment: Just to be clear, you're sharing posts in the hopes of increasing traffic, but you don't want Google to index them (which might also help to increase your traffic)? How are you sharing them? Do you have the [search result settings](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1151728?hl=en) disabled?

Comment: Yes i am sharing the posts to increase traffic but for some reasons the Google+ page indexes gets more significance than my original source (website link). That's where the problem comes in am not sure if users will be patient enough to go through the Google+ to get access to the content. And thanks that forum helped now turned off index feature of my page didn't thought it would be that easy. Thanks again

Comment: See this post for information on how Google handles duplicate content like this: [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)

Comment: I don't know of any way to control indexing on Google+.   You may just have to not duplicate your content there, or only duplicate a snippet with a "read more" link.

Comment: I believe the general tactic is to put the primary content on your site and teaser content on G+. It does not have to be a snippet, just enough to get a good taste and want more. Cheers!!